# Visual Web Developer 2010 suddenly making tables

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

I have a navigation menu defined in visual web developer 2010 express using a bunch of  tags.  This worked as expected until a few days ago, when I must have accidentally changed something.  I noticed the styles were no longer getting displayed on the menu, so I examined my master page and compared it to a default master page.

My page generates this for a menu item:

```
<table id="ctl00_NavigationMenu" class="menu ctl00_NavigationMenu_2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
    <td onmouseover="Menu_HoverStatic(this)" onmouseout="Menu_Unhover(this)" onkeyup="Menu_Key(event)" id="ctl00_NavigationMenun0"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_NavigationMenu_1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Whereas the default master page generates this:

```
<li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
```

The problem seems to be that a table is being generated from the MenuItem tag instead of a list.  How did I do this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shot in the dark, but did you make any changes to your framework version?  When upgrading a project to 4.0, the following line gets added to your `web.config` which changes the way some tags are rendered:

```
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" ...
```

If it's there, you might try removing it...

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.  I've spent 3 hours or so trying to figure out where I screwed up, and that was it.

Comment: Genius?  No... well... maybe...  But it's more of a "been there, done that, lost hair" before type thing this time...  Glad to help...